# How to get belongsTo object in controller with Ember Data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am developing a web site using Ember JS and Ember Data.
I am displaying a list of OrderItems, and each OrderItem has a belongsTo relationship to Product. In the object controller of the OrderItem, I need to calculate the line total (quantity * product price).
My issue is that I cannot get a hold of the product data.

**Models**

```
//OrderItem
export default DS.Model.extend({
    order: DS.belongsTo('order'),
    product: DS.belongsTo('product'),
    quantity: DS.attr('number'),
    lineTotal: DS.attr('number')
});

//Product
export default DS.Model.extend({
    productNo: DS.attr('string'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    shortDescription: DS.attr('string'),
    longDescription: DS.attr('string'),
    price: DS.attr('number'),
    stock: DS.attr('number'),
});
```

**Controllers**

```
//store/checkout-lines
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    itemController: 'store/checkout-line'
});

//store/checkout-line
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    orderlinetotal: function(){
        var item = this.get('model');
        var quantity = item.get('quantity');
        var product = item.get('product');
        var lineTotal = quantity * product.get('price');
        return lineTotal;
    }.property('quantity'),
    actions: {
        deleteItem: function(){
            var item = this.get('model');
            this.store.deleteRecord(item);
            item.save();
        }
    }
});
```

This line:

```
var product = item.get('product');
```

returns an ember object

but this:

```
product.get('price');
```

returns undefined...

How can I solve this issue? I've tried to use .then(), like this:

```
product.then(function(){this.get('price');});
```

but then I get the error get(...).then is not a function, because product is not a promise but an Ember data object.

***EDIT***

This is the order model

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    customer: DS.belongsTo('customer'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    status: DS.attr('number'),
    totalPrice: DS.attr('number'),
    orderItems: DS.hasMany('order-item', {async: true})
});
```

This is the json responses (in the same order as they are executed)

```
//GET /orders/58
{"order":
    {"id":58,
    "description":null,
    "name":null,
    "status":2,
    "totalPrice":5000.0000,
    "orderItems":[36]}
}


//GET /orderItems?orderId=58
{"orderItem":[
    {"id":36,
    "product":2,
    "quantity":1,
    "order":58,
    "lineTotal":5000.0000}
]}

//GET /product/2
{"product":
    {"id":2,
    "productNo":"0001-01",
    "name": "Extreme Volume Mascara",
    "shortDescription":"Sort",
    "longDescription":"The best volumizing mascara there is",
    "price":50.0000,
    "stock":1000}
}
```

***Edit 2***

I found a solution to my problem. Not sure if this is the right way to do this, but I got the idea in a comment here at [the ember discuss forum](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/promises-and-computed-properties/3333/10)

I figured that the product data was loaded correctly, because I am displaying the properties in the store/checkout-lines template (and because I can see the HTTP request). But for some reason, in the store/chekout-line controller I could not get the data of the product, EXCEPT for the product id. Maybe the context was not properly loaded? I did how ever figure that it had something to do with the ObjectController (store/checkout-line), because if I loop throug all the orderItems in the ArrayController (store/checkout-lines) I have access to the product data.

Anyways here is my solution:

```
//store/checkout-line
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isNew: function(){
        return this.get('model').get('order').get('status') === 1;
    }.property('order.status'),
    orderlineTotal: function(k,v){
        if(arguments.length > 1){
            return v;
        }
        var self = this;
        var model = this.get('model');
        var productId = model.get('product').get('id'); //only property I have access to
        var promise = this.store.find('product', productId); //this will not call the web api, because the product is already in memory
        promise.then(function(product){
            var result = product.get('price') * model.get('quantity');
            self.set('orderlineTotal', result);
        })
    }.property('product.price', 'quantity'),
    actions: {
        deleteItem: function(){
            var item = this.get('model');
            this.store.deleteRecord(item);
            item.save();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: How are you setting up your data? Maybe the product models are not properly instantiated.

Comment: I'm using the Ember REST Adapter. Using Firebug and console.log(product) i can see the ember object and that all properties including price is correct.

Comment: When did you do `console.log(product)`? In your `orderlinetotal` method? And also, how did you see that the properties were set correctly? Another thing, you might want to add `product.price` as a dependency on the `orderlinetotal`. This makes sure that if the product price changes (assuming it works), the property will be updated accordingly.

Comment: In the orderlinetotal method, yes. In firefox you can inspect the object that is being console logged. In the Ember object Product, in _data property all properties in the model is displayed with correct values.

Comment: I see. It's weird that even though `_data` is correctly set, doing `product.get('price')` does not return the correct value. What about the other properties of Product (name, stock, etc...)? Can you retrieve these?

Comment: I have tried all of them, and they all return undefined/null.
I did try something else thoug; order-item has DS.belongsTo('order'), too. Tried to do this.get('model').get('order').get('totalPrice'), and it works just as it is supposed to.  

The order model:
export default DS.Model.extend({
    customer: DS.belongsTo('customer'),
    status: DS.attr('number'),
    totalPrice: DS.attr('number'),
    orderItems: DS.hasMany('order-item', {async: true})
});

Comment: Will you show your json response when you hydrate your product?

Comment: Not sure if I understod what "hydrate your product" means, but here is the json response from GET product/2 {"product":
 {"id":2,
 "productNo":"0001-01",
 "name": "Extreme Volume Mascara",
 "shortDescription":"Sort",
 "longDescription":"The best volumizing mascara there is",
 "price":50.0000,
 "stock":1000}
}

Comment: Can you show the JSON that includes the order, the product and the orderitem?

Comment: Done. I've updated the question with the json responses.